# Multiple content:url Images

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive

I am trying to add multiple images to a page using CSS. I am doing it this way rather than in a more 'straight forward' way to ensure mobile compatibility (it allows me to set percentage widths for the images which allows me to get them to display at the right size on mobile).

I currently have in my stylesheet:

```
div.image {
content:url(http://example.com/example-image1.jpg);
width:100%
}

div.image2 {
content:url(http://example.com/example-image2.jpg);
width:25%
}
```

​
and then a few more images. And then in certain parts of my page:

```
<div class="image">

</div>

<div class="image2">

</div>
```

The problem I am getting is content:url only seems to be working in the first instance, that is the only picture that displays. It doesn't seem to be a problem with multiple div.s as if I set the 2nd div to the same content:url image as the first div, that image does actually display twice.

Sorry if this is a dumb/noob question...I just couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a bracket :

```
div.image2{
   content:url(http://example.com/example-image2.jpg);
   width:25%
}
```

EDIT: I tried with the bracket and it worked. I use Mozilla Firefox version 58.

Comment: Sorry just made a mistake adding the code into my question...doesn't work even with the bracket. I'll try editing. Thanks.

Comment: I tried with the bracket and it worked. I use Chrome version 59.

Comment: OK that is strange...I'll review my code one more time.

Comment: Right I see the problem...I went to Advanced Settings in Chrome and cleared Cached images and files and now it works! Thanks for testing that for me!

Comment: If I helped you and if your problem is solved, please accept my answer, thanks